# How do you pass URL Parameters to a Lambda function using AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am currently trying to create a Hello World Lambda function and test it through the API Gateway, as my intent is to provide a REST API using Lambda function. I have a very basic function handler that takes in an integer and outputs it as a string:

```
     public string FunctionHandler(int input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        return input.ToString();
    }
```

I have published this code to AWS and it seems to work. I have tested it from Visual Studio using the AWS tools as well as from the AWS Console.

I have an API setup that has a POST method with a single resource parameter called "input". When creating the method I selected Lambda Expression for Integration Type.

When I use the API Test screen to test it out, I always receive a JSON exception. Here is the output:

```
{
"errorType": "JsonReaderException",
"errorMessage": "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {.   Path '', line 1, position 1.",
"stackTrace": [
"at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadNumberValue(ReadType readType)",
"at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32()",
"at  Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)",
"at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)",
"at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)",
"at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)",
"at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )"
]
}
```

Here are the headers that are logged as well. They show the value that I am providing for input, in this case a 1:

```
Execution log for request test-request
Wed Jan 03 19:12:25 UTC 2018 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Wed Jan 03 19:12:25 UTC 2018 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /1
Wed Jan 03 19:12:25 UTC 2018 : Method request path: {input=1}
Wed Jan 03 19:12:25 UTC 2018 : Method request query string: {}
Wed Jan 03 19:12:25 UTC 2018 : Method request headers: {}
```

I dont really understand why I am receiving any sort of JSON errors. When I test via the console or Visual Studio, I simply provide a "1". No JSON formatting at all. When I test via the Console using path parameters it should essentially be a url like "mydomain.com/resource/1". It shouldnt need to parse it, but I am sure there is a good reason for it to try.

Is it even possible to pass path parameters to a Lambda function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured this out. I noticed that many people in similar threads were suggesting either using a Mapping Template to send the data in whatever format I wanted or selecting **Use Lambda Proxy Integration**. Either one of these suggestions will work, but what is confusing is how to handle it using the C# SDK.

The first parameter of your FunctionHandler will be a JObject containing the json in the request body. If you dont have a mapping template and you dont select Use Lambda Proxy Integration, this will always be empty. I decided to go with USe Lambda Proxy Integration because it seems to provide all of the details I need in well-formatted JSON.

The second important thing to note is that there is already a class that can be used to automatically deserialize the json. It provides the path params, querystring, body, and headers as simple properties that you can easily access. That is the **Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents.APIGatewayProxyRequest** (you will probably need to add the nuget package since it isnt a part of the default empty template).

So in the end my code looks like this:

```
    public APIGatewayProxyResponse FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {

        context.Logger.LogLine("Get Request\n");
        var path = "none";
        if (request.PathParameters != null && request.PathParameters.Any())
        {
            path = request.PathParameters["input"];
        }
        var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Body = "Hello World. Here are is your path param: " + path,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "application/json" }, { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" } }
        };
        return response;
    }
```